# .htaccess rewrite page with alias

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite an url like `/services/rental/faq-2/` so that the user (and robots) see `/services/rental/faq/`

This is my current .htaccess (it's Wordpress) with no successful rewrite:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/services/rental/faq/?$ /services/rental/faq-2/ [NC,L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any of the hints I searched actually worked, maybe rule order is important or (most probable) I have no idea on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Your *external* URL is /services/rental/faq[/]. This is the one produced by links in your pages, and is the one robots and users see. It is **NOT** produced by .htaccess -- .htaccess only sees *incoming* URIs.

Try moving your new RewriteRule up *before* all the other WordPress RewriteRules (after the RewriteBase).

Comment: Doesn't work, it takes me to another page `/services/guides/faq/` maybe it's a Wordpress internal problem as it seems that _slug_ (`faq`) must be unique

Comment: You're saying that `/services/rental/faq/` gets rewritten to `/services/guides/faq/`? That would have to be something internal to WP, if all you did was move that one RewriteRule up to the top. Sorry, can't help you with that issue.